# Is it possible to have auto-generated uuid primary keys in SQLAlchemy 2?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Now that SQLAlchemy 2 has a [built-in Uuid type](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Uuid) instead of relying on a custom [Backend-agnostic GUID Type](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/custom_types.html#backend-agnostic-guid-type), is there a way to have an auto-generated uuid as a primary key?

I tried this:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as so

from project import db


class User(db.Model):
    id: so.Mapped[sa.Uuid] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    username: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
```

but I get the error "sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: The type provided inside the 'id' attribute Mapped annotation is the SQLAlchemy type <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.Uuid'>. Expected a Python type instead".

I understand what the error means, but I'm not sure where to go from there. I'm just getting started with SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options, to use a UUID that is generated from python, or to use a UUID generated from the database. The type that goes in `Mapped` should be the `UUID` from python not `Uuid` from SQLAlchemy no matter what approach or database you choose. The following code shows how to generate both. I have used PostgreSQL and its corresponding function (`gen_random_uuid()`) to generate a uuid, but you can use any database function, say `uuid()` if using MySQL.

```py
from uuid import uuid4, UUID
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, mapped_column, Mapped, Session

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg://some_connection_string")

class UserWithPythonDefault(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table_with_uuid_from_python"
    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)

class UserWithServerDefault(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table_with_uuid_from_db"
    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, server_default=func.gen_random_uuid())

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    obj_with_python_default = UserWithPythonDefault()
    obj_with_server_default = UserWithServerDefault()
    session.add(obj_with_python_default)
    session.add(obj_with_server_default)
    session.commit()
```

If you go check the database, you should see two tables with one row each, both having a random UUID set.

Edit: As @YuriiMotov points out in his comment, there is a somewhat "third" option available if you are open to having your SQLAlchemy models work as a dataclass. The advantage, as he mentions is this lets you use the default value once you create the object.

```py
from uuid import uuid4, UUID
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, mapped_column, Mapped, Session, MappedAsDataclass

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class UserWithPythonDefault(MappedAsDataclass, Base):
    __tablename__ = "table_with_uuid_from_python"
    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, default_factory=uuid4)
```

Comment: I would only add that `default_factory` might be a better choice for python-side generation, since it will generate value when object is created (in `__init__()`). At the same time `default` works only when you call `commit`. Sometimes it's needed to create object and use it's autogenerated id to create another object (as a foreign key value) in the same commit. To use `default_factory` you need to inherit your `Base` from `MappedAsDataclass`: `class Base(DeclarativeBase, MappedAsDataclass):`

Comment: @YuriiMotov good point, though I would like to add that " use it's autogenerated id to create another object (as a foreign key value) " can usually be done without that, by adding the object to the relationship attribute directly :) I am not being dismissive of your suggestion btw just wanted to point it out

Comment: you are absolutely right. It was just one of possible ways. As I see, sometimes people don't use relationship attributes in their models. I also decided not to use it in my current project as an experiment)

Comment: I like the idea of my models being dataclasses so I'll probably go with that version.